# jQuery in Persian language

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want create a simple website in Persian language. I use jQuery and jQuery UI in my web page.
But when I write a tag that contains Persian language, it's not looking perfect and trustworthy. It shows many question marks in this tag.

How to solve it?

Comment: You need to a) save the page in UTF8 and b) show the page in UTF8

Comment: Do you mean that you give your elemens an ID in Persian language? Like "<div id="PERSIAN_ID_NAME"></div>"? You might want to save yourself a lot of trouble with keeping your code in plain english, and just the content in Persian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick a character encoding (UTF-8 unless you have an excellent reason to use something else) and make sure you use it everywhere (in your editor, in your database, in your HTTP responses, etc).

- [Introducing Character Sets and Encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/characters)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Setting encoding in web authoring applications](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications)

Comment: I use
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
in head.
is this Correct؟

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what encoding the data actually uses. You should use a real Content-Type HTTP header too.